# Есть ли возможность писать скечи и отлаживать их для других контроллеров в ардуино IDE (ATTINY13, ATTINY26 и др.)?

Tags: тестирование, arduino

Попалась плата, на которой ATTINY26 и трехразрядный семисегментный индикатор уже распаяны. Хочется написать и отладить в arduino IDE программу таймера, или вольтметра, экспортировать бинарный файл и залить его в контроллер через USBASP программатор. Есть несколько ATTINY13. Для них тоже хотелось что-нибудь сочинить.

Answer (score 1):

В принципе можно. Для этого нужно добавить описание микроконтроллера в файл конфигурации. С ATtiny не получится разве что осуществить заливку прошивки в микроконтроллер. Для этого потребовалось бы предварительно прошить бутлоадер через ICSP.

Кроме этого, для того, чтобы использовать функции Arduino IDE, такие какие `digitalWrite()`, `analogRead()` и т.п., нужно будет добавить поддержку микроконтроллера в заголовочные файлы. Это немного сложнее, чем добавить описание микроконтроллера в конфигурацию.